# Jmeter run transaction controllers based on if condition

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm fairly new to Jmeter. Here is my question.

I have 2 transaction controllers. Those will be run based on some if condition.

Example. I have transaction_controller_01 and transaction_controller_02.

I have a variable called 'type'. 
When type = "user", transaction_controller_01 should be run.
When type = "admin", transaction_controller_02 should be run.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put both Transaction Controller under If Controller

First If Condition will be "${type} == "user"

Second If Condition will be  "${type} == "admin"